# Animating rectangle color when changing Fill property

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I have a rectangle in WPF defined in this way;

```
<Rectangle x:Name="redBrush"   Width="20" Height="20"  Fill="{Binding RectColor}" Stroke="Black" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2">
```

I would like to animate the changing of the color from one to another.

I tried with something like this:

```
    <Rectangle x:Name="redBrush"   Width="20" Height="20"  Fill="{Binding NewColor}" Stroke="Black" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2">
        <Rectangle.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Rectangle.MouseEnter">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="redBrush"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).Color" To="{Binding NewColor}" Duration="0:0:3" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Rectangle.Triggers>
    </Rectangle>
```

But I have two problems with this approach. Which RoutedEvent do I have to use? and the To= property in ColorAnimation does not work.

Could you help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Storyboards are freezable objects, you can't set their properties using bindings.

A workaround would be to generate a Storyboard every time Fill DP is changed:

```
private SolidColorBrush _rectColor;
public SolidColorBrush RectColor {

    get {return _rectColor;}
    set {
        _rectColor = value;
        _sbFillAnimation= CreateFillAnimationStoryboard(_rectColor);
        _sbFillAnimation.Begin();
    }
}

private Storyboard _sbFillAnimation;

private Storyboard CreateFillAnimationStoryboard(SolidColorBrush rectColor) {
    Storyboard sb = new Storyboard() { Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), BeginTime = TimeSpan.Zero};

    ColorAnimation colAnim = new ColorAnimation();
    colAnim.From = rectColor.Color;
    colAnim.To = Colors.Gray;
    colAnim.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
    colAnim.AutoReverse = false;

    sb.Children.Add(colAnim);

    Storyboard.SetTarget(colAnim, redBrush);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(colAnim, new PropertyPath("Fill.Color"));


    return sb;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The idea seems really good.Do you have idea why I got error on 
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(ca, new PropertyPath("(Rectangle.Fill).Color"));
? 
"Cannot resolve all property references in the property path '(Rectangle.Fill).Color'. Verify that applicable objects support the properties."

Comment: mhmm... 
It not works for me
"Cannot resolve all property references in the property path '(Rectangle.Fill).Color'. Verify that applicable objects support the properties."

Comment: @Lorenzo522 tried to make it work, still working on it

Comment: Edited my post. It SHOULD work but it doesn't (no exception anymore and the storyboard completes but no changes shows up)